# Как оформить страницу ошибки 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, error404

У меня есть сайт, зеркало другого сайта.

Мне нужно оформить страницу ошибки 404 для данного сайта, так как это тоже учитывается поисковыми системами для SEO продвижения. Сайт построен на собственном фреймворке.

И да, файл `.htaccess` лежит в корне сайта.

Я пробовал 2 способа:

- в файле `.htaccess` прописать `ErrorDocument 404 ~directory/404.php` (соответственно что вместо директории абсолютный путь к файлу чезер домен.
- второй способ, я создал контроллер и роут на error, и в случае любой ошибки через файл `.htaccess` я перенаправлял на /error однако такая запись также ничего не дала.

Подскажите, как можно решить мою проблему, а так же, какие скрины и части кода нужно прикрепить?

Вот код `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
#

RewriteEngine on


RewriteBase /

AddType image/x-icon .png 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.xml [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Вот код роутера, со всеми преобразованиями:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: USER
 * Date: 20.02.2019
 * Time: 19:40
 */

class Router
{

    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $routePath = ROOT . '/config/routes.php';
        $this->routes = include($routePath);
    }

    // Return Type

    private function getURI()
    {
        if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path){
            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {
                // Получаем внутренний путь их внешнего согласно правилу

                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);

                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                $controllerName = array_shift($segments).'Controller';
                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                $actionName = 'action'.ucfirst(array_shift($segments));
                $parameters = $segments;

                $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' . $controllerName . '.php';
                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    include_once ($controllerFile);
                }
                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;
                $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);

                if ($result != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Вот сам файл `index.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: USER
 * Date: 20.02.2019
 * Time: 17:59
 */
// FRONT CONTROLLER

// Общие настройки

session_start();

// Подключение файлов системы

define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Autoload.php');

//Вызов Router

$router = new Router();
$router->run();
```

Comment: _> вместо директории абсолютный путь к файлу чезер домен_ Как это? Путь должен начинаться со слэша, и вычисляется он относительно корня сайта.

Comment: я пробовал и так, и читал, что можно использовать абсолютный путь к файлу, `https://zerkalo1x/404.php` -вот так вот например

Comment: Если указать полный URL, как вы показали, то Apache будет выдавать 301 код и перенаправлять бразуер туда. Не очень круто для SEO.

Comment: @mymedia я вот сейчас поставил `AllowOverride All` в `.htaccess` и получил 500 даже по домену.

Comment: может, есть в журнале ошибок какие подсказки, что произошло?

Comment: @mymedia в самой ошибке missconfiguration идет, а вот журнала ошибок на файловом клиенте не предусмотрено, я так понимаю(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90799/discussion-between-mymedia-and--).

Comment: У меня есть ответ, похожий на ваш ответ. Так вот данный ответ я считаю правильным![![Кусок конфига из nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW4CQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW4CQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фрагмент ниже говорит что любой запрос к несуществующему файлу будет отправлен на обработку в `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Иначе говоря, дополнительные директивы Apache никак не помогут вам настроить обработку страницы 404, так как вы уже сказали веб-серверу что обработкой несуществующих страниц занимаетесь сами.

Значит это вы должны выдавать код 404 если страница вам неизвестна. Подходящим местом это сделать будет конец функции `run()`:

```
public function run()
{
    $uri = $this->getURI();

    foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {
        // обычное содержимое функции...             
    }

    // затем, в самом конце
    if (!isset($result) || $result === null) {
        // подадим соответствующий HTTP код
        http_response_code(404);

        // опционально показываем что-то на странице
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте полный вариант ответа к функции run (), так как в данном случае, люди могут не понять, что значит, в самом конце

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич так понятней?

Comment: через 9 часов присужу вам 100 репутации

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич как скажите, спешки нет